# Which countries (besides China) have called for an "immediate ceasefire" in Gaza?

Tags: china, israel, comparative-politics, gaza

AFP reported [that](https://www.barrons.com/news/china-shocked-by-and-strongly-condemns-gaza-hospital-strike-366f5b41):

> China's foreign ministry said Wednesday it was "shocked by and strongly condemns" a strike on a hospital in Gaza that killed hundreds, calling for an "immediate ceasefire".
>
> "China is shocked by and strongly condemns the heavy casualties caused by the attack on a Gaza hospital," Beijing's foreign ministry said, adding: "China calls for an **immediate ceasefire** and an end to the war".

Which other countries have joined China in calling for an immediate ceasefire?

Comment: FWTW, apparently Xi personally repeated the same message https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2023-10-19/xi-calls-for-gaza-ceasefire-in-first-public-comment-since-crisis

Answer (score 14):

Here are the countries I found so far. I turned this answer into a community wiki, so feel free to add other countries you find.

| Country | Date calling for ceasefire |
| --- | --- |
| Russia | [October 7 2023](https://tass.com/politics/1686405) |
| Brazil | [October 11 2023](https://www.usnews.com/news/world/articles/2023-10-11/brazils-lula-calls-for-ceasefire-humanitarian-intervention-in-israel-palestinian-conflict) |
| Pakistan | [October 16 2023](https://dunyanews.tv/en/Pakistan/763078-Pakistan-calls-for-immediate-ceasefire,-lifting-of-Gaza-blockade) |
| Gulf Cooperation Council (Bahrain, Kuwait, Oman, Qatar, Saudi Arabia, and the United Arab Emirates) | [October 17 2023](https://gulfnews.com/world/mena/gcc-calls-for-an-immediate-ceasefire-lifting-siege-on-gaza-1.1697568987855) |
| Malaysia | [October 18 2023](https://www.malaymail.com/news/malaysia/2023/10/17/pm-anwar-urges-israel-to-call-for-ceasefire-in-gaza-and-renounce-politics-of-dispossession/96720) |
| Indonesia | [October 18 2023](https://www.benarnews.org/english/news/indonesian/ceasefire-calls-10182023152932.html) |
| Thailand | [October 18 2023](https://www.benarnews.org/english/news/indonesian/ceasefire-calls-10182023152932.html) |
| China | [October 18 2023](https://www.barrons.com/news/china-shocked-by-and-strongly-condemns-gaza-hospital-strike-366f5b41) |
| Ireland | [October 18 2023](https://www.irishtimes.com/politics/2023/10/18/varadkar-calls-for-immediate-humanitarian-ceasefire-in-israel-hamas-war/) |

Comment: Russia doesn't want the war to be prolonged and to deplete the American bank account that's funding Ukraine?

Comment: @user1271772 Maybe its government wants so, but it at least pretends otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Many, [22](https://www.msn.com/en-ae/news/other/arab-countries-at-un-demand-immediate-ceasefire-in-gaza-after-hospital-tragedy/ar-AA1iqUSm) Arab countries at the United Nations joined in demanding an immediate ceasefire in Gaza.

The number 22 presumably refers to the members of the Arab League. Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_world):

> The Arab world is at its minimum defined as the 19 states where Arabic is natively spoken. At its maximum it consists of the 22 members of the Arab League, an international organization, which on top of the 19 states also includes the Comoros, Djibouti and Somalia.

Answer (score 2):

This has probably gone slightly unnoticed but on Oct 16 a group of countries [proposed](https://research.un.org/en/docs/sc/quick/meetings/2023) S/2023/772 to the UN Security Council. It was not adopted (votes: 5-4-6). The text included:

> Calls for an immediate, durable and fully respected humanitarian
> ceasefire;

The draft was advanced by 26 countries, if I counted them right:

> Bahrain, Bangladesh, Belarus, Djibouti, Egypt, Eritrea, Indonesia,
> Jordan, Kuwait, Lebanon, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Mauritania,
> Nicaragua, Oman, Pakistan, Qatar, Russian Federation, Saudi
> Arabia, Sudan, Türkiye, United Arab Emirates, Bolivarian
> Republic of Venezuela, Yemen and Zimbabwe

China was not on the drafters' list. But it [did](https://crsreports.congress.gov/product/pdf/download/R/R47754/R47754.pdf/) vote in favor (as did Gabon and Mozambique which were not among the drafters either).

> The draft resolution did not mention Hamas. Five members voted in
> favor of the resolution (China, Gabon, Mozambique, Russia, and the United Arab Emirates), four voted against (France, Japan, the United Kingdom, and the United States) and six abstained

Later on, Russia tried to amend S/2023/773 with a similar para (via S/2023/776), but that was also not adopted.

Answer (score 1):

Brunei. Ministry of Foreign Affairs ([2023-10-09](https://www.mfa.gov.bn/Lists/Press%20Room/news.aspx?id=1072&source=https://www.mfa.gov.bn/site/home.aspx)):

> We urge all parties to immediately cease all forms of violence and exercise utmost restraint.

---

Venezuela. Ministry of Foreign Affairs ([2023-10-12](https://mppre.gob.ve/comunicado/venezuela-condena-ataques-misiles-israel-danaron-aeropuertos-sirios/)):

> La República Bolivariana de Venezuela hace un llamado a la Comunidad Internacional para intensificar los esfuerzos basados en los principios internacionales consagrados en la Carta de las Naciones Unidas, que conlleven al cese inmediato al fuego en Gaza y en toda la región, evitando más afectaciones y víctimas humanas.

ChatGPT translation:

> The Bolivarian Republic of Venezuela calls on the International Community to intensify efforts based on the international principles enshrined in the Charter of the United Nations, leading to an immediate ceasefire in Gaza and throughout the region, avoiding further damage and human casualties.

---

Bangladesh. Ministry of Foreign Affairs ([2023-10-08](https://mofa.gov.bd/site/press_release/8de905ff-c0b9-4d42-b5cf-d9eef7aa0a69)):

> We urge both Israeli and Palestinians to exercise maximum restraint and calls for immediate ceasefire to avoid further loss of innocent lives from both sides.